# Miktex package does not succeed: miktex-fc-cache.exe

Tags: installation, windows-10, package, miktex

I reinstalled miktex multiple times now, but I still get the same error, when updating or installing new packages: The executed process did not succeed (fileName="[path to miktex 2.9 directory]\miktex\bin\x64\miktex-fc-cache.exe", exitCode="1").
I installed it only for my user and let it update packages on the fly.
I already checked, whether the path name contains any unusual symbols or spaces, but the only instance of a space is the very own directory "MiKTeX 2.9".

Unfortunately I don't know how to interpret the [miktex report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQkhz.png), so I can't find the error myself.

I also tried installing TeXLive but had the same problem, that it could not install any packages.

Comment: Hi there, does this solve your problem? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/329125/miktex-installation-fails-with-executed-process-did-not-succeed

Comment: Unfortunately not. I never changed any names and checked, whether windows screwed that up.

Comment: Despite there was a working installation on my system for year and more, recently I have faced a series of problems with the MikTeX to use in VS Code with Latex Workshops. Unfortunately, any usual reinstall and path modification options did not help. Give a try TeXLive one more time. I am happy with it now.